# Javascript fadeIn() transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that switches the opacity of an image after a certain delay:

```
$(".pattern-overlay").css("background","black").delay(2000).queue(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)").dequeue();
});
```

How can I make the transition look smooth instead of just switching the colors directly?

Comment: Use `.animate()`

Comment: How can I implement it on my code?

Comment: Why don't you use addClass() with css transition? Or just transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example with `animate()`:

```js
$(".pattern-overlay").css("background","black").delay(2000).animate({
    opacity: 0.4,
}, 1000);
```

```css
.pattern-overlay {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pattern-overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hide function in Jquery with timeout. You can checkout this page for hiding of your DOM elements with animation. http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Sample Code :

```
$("#yourElementId").hide("slow");
```

Comment: Sorry, the div disappears completely